# Retrieve specific text from HTML snippet using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I've following HTML snippet and out of it I want to retrieve only `3` text:

```
<div class="assigned" ng-repeat="counte">
  3
 <div class="ng-binding">Assigned</div>
</div>
```

But when I use following, it returns `3Assigned`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(//div[@class='assigned'])).getText();
```

I only want to retrieve `3`, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

When you evaluate a nodes set's text, it returns the concatenated text of all `text` children, grandchildren, etc.

You can use the `[1]` indexer as a suffix to obtain just the first text:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='assigned']/text())[1]")).getText();
```

Comment: I tried it but it gives me error: `(//div[@class='assigned']/text())[1] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement`

Comment: Do we need the getText() in the end ? try after removing the getText();

Comment: The problem here is that the xpath returns a scalar string, not a node. I'm not close to a Se installation right now, but there might be another method instead of `By.xpath` which returns a string not an object  (you don't need to find an element, you just need to evaluate my xpath on the document to obtain the result)

Answer (score 0):

Try out with :

xpath - > `//div[@class='ng-binding']/preceding-sibling::text()`

Comment: Hope this might have helped?

Comment: Is it? I tried with your snippet that you have provided. This xpath is working great. Can you please provide the o/p using this xpath?